# Why the `using` keyword cannot be used for static class member?

Tags: c++, class, c++11, static, using

`using` makes an identifier to be visible in the global scope, but why cannot be used for `static` class member?

For example `using std::string::size_type;` is wrong. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why cannot be used for `static` class member?

You have misunderstood the use of [`using`-declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration#Explanation)

> `Using`-declarations can be used to introduce **namespace members into
> [other namespaces and block scopes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace)**, or **to introduce a base class
> members into derived class definitions**.

The `std::string::size_type;` is an *[member type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string#Member_types)* defined in `std::string` class, not a namespace or function in any namespaces.

Therefore, with `using`, you can only specify/declare the [alias type for a type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias). For example:

```
using string_size_type = std::string::size_type;
```

Comment: For example, "struct Test { static int a;}; using Test::a;"

Comment: So are there any way to mention static class member without :: operator?

Comment: @AlanJian I have updated the answer. For the static members of a class, this is not possible. But for a function in any namespaces-scope this could be: https://godbolt.org/z/xWM551